# How do you multiply these logarithms and find the domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm supposed to solve for $x$ and find the domain. I know that adding two logs together is multiplication of the numbers, but what if two logs are completely multiplying each other?
$$\log_{10}(0.1x^2)\log_{10}x=1$$

Comment: What do you mean by "find the domain"?

Comment: Possible hint. Since $\log(x^2) = 2\log(x)$ you can rewrite this as a quadratic equation in $\log(x)$, solve for that and then for $x$.

Comment: The domain of the left side is $x>0$ [input to any log needs to be positive, so first log restricts to nonzero $x$ as it's squared, but second log restricts $x$ to be positive.

Comment: Not much (as far as what you've asked is concerned): there is the identity $\log a\log b=\log (b^{\log a})$ for $a,b> 0$, but that's not quite the way you were meant to face the exercise.

Comment: $log_{10}(0.1x^2)log_{10}(x)=(-1+2log_{10}(x))log_{10}(x)=2log_{10}^2(x)-log_{10}(x)=1$

$2log_{10}^2(x)=log_{10}(10)+log_{10}(x)$

$2log_{10}^2(x)=log_{10}(10x)$
Beyond that, I'm not really sure, but hopefully that is helpful

Answer (score 3):

The domain of the LHS of the original equation is $x\in(0,\infty)$, because of the presence of $\log_{10}x$.

By logarithm rules (justified by the domain of $x$), we can take the multiple of 0.1 and the square out of $0.1x^2$:
$$\log_{10}(0.1x^2)\log_{10}x=(\log_{10}0.1+2\log_{10}x)\log_{10}x=(2\log_{10}x-1)\log_{10}x=1$$
We denote $\log_{10}x=y$:
$$(2y-1)y=2y^2-y=1$$
$$2y^2-y-1=0$$
Solving for $y$, we get $y=1$ and $y=-\frac12$, corresponding to solutions of $x=10$ and $x=\frac1{\sqrt{10}}=0.316\dots$

Comment: While it is true that $2\log_{10} x = \log_{10} x^2$ for $x > 0$, the domain of $\log_{10} x^2$ is $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ since $x^2 > 0$ unless $x = 0$.  Hence, $\log_{10} x^2 = 2\log_{10} |x|$, which you will notice also has domain $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But there's still a lone $\log_{10}x$ in the original equation.

Comment: I am aware of that.  What I am saying does not change the answer.  Perhaps it would be better to point out that the domain of the expression $\log_{10} (0.1x^2)\log_{10} x$ at the start of the answer rather than at the end, which would then justify your assertion that $\log_{10} x^2 = 2\log_{10} x$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig done.